# Show that limit of sequence does not exist

Tags: sequences-and-series

Problem:

> Let $x_n=\begin{cases}\frac 1n &\text{if $n$ is odd} \\ 1 & \text{if $n$ is even}  \end{cases}$ and show that the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ does not exist.

I am trying to find a contradiction, but I am having trouble. Am I on the right track though as far as my proof is concerned?

Work:
Suppose $x \not=0$. Let $\epsilon = \frac{|x-0|}2=\frac{|x|}2$. Since $x_n \to x$, for $\epsilon = \frac{|x|}2$, there exists an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \ge n_0$ implies $|x_n-x| < \frac{|x|}2 \implies \frac{|x|}2 < |x_n|$. By the Archimedian Principle, there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $0 < \frac 1n < \frac{|x|}2$.

If $x = 0$, then ... (not finished with this part, still working on it)

Answer (score 2):

By Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem and taking the two subsequences formed by taking the even and odd numbered(indexed) terms respectively you get that there is no limit(odd indexed terms converge to 0 while the other sequence converges to 1).

Comment: My class has not learned that theorm yet. I just want to use neighborhoods as a proof.

Comment: Then, think about what happens when two subsequences of a sequence converge to 2 separate values. If my opinion matters, go for the most intuitive way when doing mathematics, the class won't be later... you'll be all alone...

Answer (score 1):

There is a following theorem.

> **$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=a \iff \lim_{n\to \infty}x_{2n}= \lim_{n\to \infty}x_{2n-1}=a$**

It is easy to see: $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_{2n}=0\not=1 =\lim_{n\to \infty}x_{2n-1}$.

Therefor this limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

An argument using **only** the definition of limit:

Suppose that $x_n\to L$ for some $L$. Then, $L$ must be $1$ because if $L\neq 1$, there would be arbitrarily large even $n$ for which $|x_n-L|=|1-L|>\frac{1}{2}|1-L|$. But with $L=1$, there are arbitrarily large odd $n\geq 3$ for which $|x_n-1|=|\frac{1}{n}-1|>\frac{1}{2}$. So $L=1$ cannot be the limit of $x_n$.

In sum, the existence of a limit $L$ leads to a contradiction.